# Find space in a list

Tags: string, list, coldfusion

I have a list (below) that is the output from an Excel table. The Excel table has 3 columns: `Month, Col1, Col2` and the output format is CSV.

```
January,630648,97646 February,576204,87616 March,998287,142008 April,782340,118664 May,1678775,205862 June,1976671,295065 July,3349937,438844 August,0,0 September,0,0 October,0,0 November,0,0 December,0,0
```

I want to display this as an HTML table. I tried using List and Array functions, but could not achieve the desired result. How can I change the empty space to a delimiter, or is there a better way to do this?

**Update from comments:**

I am using cfspreadsheet to read an excel table with 3 columns

```
 <cfspreadsheet src="../../../../file.xlsx" 
    action="read" 
    name="myquery" 
    sheetname="2014" 
    rows="6-17" columns="10,11,12" 
    format="csv" 
    columnnames="Month,Col1,Col2" 
    headerrow="4" 
    excludeheaderrow="false">
```

When I used the replace function; it did not do anything to the list. I then tried `ListChangeDelims` as suggested. However, that just changed the `,` to `;` but the space remained as it is.

Comment: Add the language tag.

Comment: @user3879362, what have you tried until now?

Comment: I tried to change the space to ; delimeter but could not. It does not find the space even using the Find function. REReplace function too does not work when I try to replace the space with another delim.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the code that you've tried.

Comment: You mention that your output is three columns, but we see a long list. How are you outputting this? If it's a CSV file I'd expect a carriage return (CHR(13)) and/or a line feed (CHR(10)) between each set of three. Perhaps that's where the breakdown is.

Comment: @FishBelowtheIce - No maybe about it. That is exactly what is happening, due to the use of `format="csv"`. You should post that as an answer. That said, I have no idea why they are returning the results as CSV instead of a query object. Then outputting the query columns as usual.

Comment: @user3879362 - Do not rely on visual inspection to reliably identify white space characters. Check the ascii values of the characters instead. Also browsers/html 101, white space is collapsed. So what appeared to be an "empty space" was actually some sort of new line.

Answer (score 1):

A list is just a string, so use one of the string functions.

```
replace(myString," ",";","all")
```

will replace all the spaces in the string with semi-colons.

---

You could also use `ListChangeDelims()` and convert the spaces to the delimiter that you want.

```
ListChangeDelims(list, new_delimiter [, delimiters, includeEmptyValues ])
```

So, this would change spaces and commas to semi-colons:

```
ListChangeDelims(myList,";",", ")
```

It's important to have both the `space` and the comma in the delimiters attribute.

Comment: Thank You for your solution ... Please check below what I am trying

Step 1 : I am using cfspreadsheet to read an excel table with 3 columnss

***************************
<cfspreadsheet src="../../../../file.xlsx" action="read"  name="myquery" sheetname="2014" rows="6-17" columns="10,11,12" format="csv" columnnames="Month,Col1,Col2" headerrow="4" excludeheaderrow="false">
***************************


Step2: When I used the replace function; it did not do anything to the list. The ListChnageDelims just changed the "," to ";" but the space remained as it is

Comment: @user3879362: This is information that should be in your question. Please edit it. Also, did you remember to use a space as well as a comma in the third argument of `ListChangeDelims`?

Comment: *This is information that should be in your question. Please edit it* Then delete the redundant comment. Having said that .. why use `format="csv"` at all? Simpler to just read the results into a query object, then cfoutput the columns as usual.

Comment: I did not try this. Instead, for now, I imported the excel data into the database and used cfquery to play around with display. Thanks for the help.